# problems trying to get tweets from different zip codes

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I am trying to get tweets from different zip codes.For doing this, I am using latitude and longitude values for each zip code. So far I want to get 3 tweets for each zip code(I have 2 zip codes), but it is working only for one zip code.
Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            var lat=[41.9716,42.0411];
            var lng=[-87.7026,-87.6900];
            $(document).ready(function() {
            for(var i=1; i<2; i++)
            {
                $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=business&geocode='+lat[i]+','+lng[i]+',5mi&lang=en&callback=?', function(data) {
                var data = data.results;
                var html = "";  
                for(var j=0; j<3;j++){
                    html += "<div style='width:600px;border:solid thin blue'><img src='"+data[j].profile_image_url+"'/><a href='http://twitter.com/" + data[j].from_user + "'>@"+ data[j].from_user + "</a>: " + data[j].text + "</div>";
            } 
            $('.content'+i).html(html);
            }); }
            });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content1"></div>
    <div class="content2"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 problems with your code:

1) If you want to iterate 2 times, your `for` function should be like this: `for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)`

2) You must have in consideration that the function that gets called in  `$.getJSON` runs asynchronously, so when that function gets called the `for` will have already finished, therefore you can't use the `i` value with that purpose inside that function.

So, after correcting those 2 things in your code you should be able to get what you want. Try with something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            var lat = [41.9716, 42.0411];
            var lng = [-87.7026, -87.6900];
            var count = 1;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=business&geocode=' + lat[i] + ',' + lng[i] + ',5mi&lang=en&callback=?', function (data) {                        
                        var data = data.results;
                        var html = "";
                        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                            html += "<div style='width:600px;border:solid thin blue'><img src='" + data[j].profile_image_url + "'/><a href='http://twitter.com/" + data[j].from_user + "'>@" + data[j].from_user + "</a>: " + data[j].text + "</div>";
                        }
                        $('.content' + count++).html(html);
                    });
                }
            });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content1"></div>
    <div class="content2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! My first mistake is obvious :) I was trying with different values for i, and I forgot i=1. It is working great now!